# Disable Doxygen pre-processing while including macro/define documentation

Tags: macros, doxygen

Is there a way to set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = NO` while making sure that documentation for macros will still be included?

For example, it's easy to set `PREDEFINED = __cplusplus`, but I would rather not have to do that for every single `#define` that Doxygen might not predefine (i.e. `__GNUC__`, etc).

Comment: For now, I went with `PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN` coupled with `#if ... || defined(DOXYGEN)`, but I'm still interested to know if there's a better/cleaner way.

Comment: I don't think this is possbile. Doxygen seems to require `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` in order to include documentation of `#define`s (and issues a warning if this option is set to `NO`). Can I ask why you are trying to do this?

Comment: Basically, I have this relatively large project with lots of [compiler/system dependent `#define`s](https://github.com/marciof/Eon/blob/master/library/util.h), that I still want documented, but that I would like to not have to list each and every single definition for the `PREDEFINED` option.

Comment: You don't have to list all the `#defines` you want documented. Leave `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES` in your configuration file and just include the [`def`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmddef) command in your comment blocks.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that'll work because the `def` command still requires Doxygen to be able to find the associated `#define` (which it won't if it's conditionally defined based on e.g. `__cplusplus`, and assuming `PREDEFINE` doesn't list it). I tried, and I got _warning: documentation for unknown define ... found_, causing it to be skipped.